# Do NT Service accounts need to be SysAdmin when using Domain Accounts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, security

I'm not sure if I'm googling for the wrong thing but I can't find an answer. We're running SQL 2014. The SQL Server and SQL Agent processes are both running under Domain Managed Service Accounts.

When SQL was installed `NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER`, `NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT`, `NT SERVICE\SQLWriter`, `NT SERVICE\Winmgmt` are all setup as `SysAdmins`.

If I am running SQL and SQL Agent as a Domain user, do I still need these NT Service accounts, and/or do they need to be SysAdmin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I am running SQL and SQL Agent as a Domain user, do I still need these NT Service accounts, and/or do they need to be SysAdmin?

Even if you are running SQL server as domain account, keep those `NT SERVICE\*` as is.

From BOL :

> **Virtual accounts** in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7 **are managed local accounts** that provide the following features to simplify service administration. The virtual account is auto-managed, and the virtual account can access the network in a domain environment. If the default value is used for the service accounts during SQL Server setup on Windows Server 2008 R2 or Windows 7, a virtual account using the instance name as the service name is used, in the format `NT SERVICE\<SERVICENAME>`

These logins are members of the sysadmin fixed server role, so they can do anything in the Database Engine. Keep them in `SYSADMIN` role even if you are using Domain account. See [SQL Server Per-service SID Login and Privileges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504(SQL.110).aspx#Logins) section.

A really good answer detailing above stuff - [Service/Database Accounts - NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER & NT SERVICE\SQLSERVERAGENT … what are they for ?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e6bb2de-8fd0-45de-ab02-d59bbe05f72e/servicedatabase-accounts-nt-servicemssqlserver-nt-servicesqlserveragent-what-are-they-for?forum=sqlsecurity)

> These accounts can't be selected in the list of available built-in accounts, local accounts or domain accounts. **This is because they are services, not accounts. They have a security identifier (SID) in Windows, but Windows knows they aren't real users. Windows can authenticate them, but they don't have passwords that any human can use.** If you run `lusrmgr.msc` and look at the groups, you will see groups like SQLServerMSSQLUser$computername$MSSQLSERVER and NT SERVICE\MSSQLSERVER is a member of the group.

Comment: My experience differs to what BOL says. When installing SQL I specified the domain user, but the NT Service accounts were still created. Also, I'm still confused as to why I need to keep them. If the process is running as a domain user then why do these accounts still need access (or need to exist at all)? Does SQL still use them?

Comment: @Greg when you install sql server with domain account, still `NT service accounts` will be created. You need to keep them as they are since they are services - not accounts even though they have a SID associated with them.  Read the links that I have cited.