# NT SERVICE accounts should be sysadmins?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, permissions, security, service-accounts

I have the following query to get me a list of `sysadmins` in the current server:

```
select 'ServerRole' = SUSER_NAME(rm.role_principal_id), 
       'MemberName' = lgn.name ,
       'Status'= Case when lgn.is_disabled=0 then 'Enabled' 
                                             else 'Disabled' 
                 end 
from sys.server_role_members rm 
INNER JOIN  sys.server_principals lgn 
        ON rm.member_principal_id = lgn.principal_id 
where rm.role_principal_id = SUSER_ID('sysadmin')
```

[image]

Should it be a concern that the accounts starting with `NT SERVICE` are `sysadmin`?

the sql server agent service is running under the account shown above in the item number 10, so maybe the number 7 is even redundant, how can I find it out?

There is a similar question:

[Is it viable to attribute permissions to SQL Server virtual accounts (NT Service\SQLSERVERAgent, etc)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51470/is-it-viable-to-attribute-permissions-to-sql-server-virtual-accounts-nt-service?rq=1)

Comment: Yes they need to be sysadmin i mean the NT accounts as needed by db engine during sql installation.

Comment: @BeginnerDBA do you have any reference for that?

Comment: @kin has the explanation here -- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114919/do-nt-service-accounts-need-to-be-sysadmin-when-using-domain-accounts